# Android : Search Icon not showing on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As the title says I am trying to add an icon (for search purposes) in my Action Bar  but all I get is the item's title in the three dot menu. Here is the code I use.

**menu_main.xml :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    </menu>
```

**The way I inflate the menu :**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Do you guys know why this happens ?

**PS: I have holo.light as default theme for my app.**

Comment: What is the superclass of your class? Activity or ActionBarActivity/AppCompatActivity?

Comment: if search is the only one option of your `ActionBar` take a look at searchable interface. Simple and useful http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: @Mattia I am using fragments so its FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some things for the native action bar (e.g., inheriting from `FragmentActivity`) and some things for the appcompat-v7 action bar backport (e.g., `app:showAsAction`).

Change `menu_main.xml` to this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_search" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code this will work:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="action_search" />
```

in your code you are using app:showAsAction="always" this is wrong use android:showAsAction="always"